# SpringMvc-Tomcat8-Hibernate4-Centos

Tags: spring, hibernate, centos, tomcat8

My project work on Windows - Spring IDE - Tomcat v8.0 for windows, MySql5. 
Project also work on java7, Tomcat7.
All my class are annotated automaticaly. 
Problem is when I deploy project on Centos where I have java8, Tomcat8 
and I have got an exception.
Please some sugestion to resolve a problem.

Here are exception on linux:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'homeController':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field: rs.co.master.service.UserRulesService
>   rs.co.master.bean.HomeController.userRulesService; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
>   bean with name 'UserRulesService': Injection of autowired dependencies 
>   failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field: private rs.co.master.dao.UserRulesDao
>   rs.co.master.service.UserRulesServiceImpl.userRulesDao; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
>   with name 'UserRulesDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:
>   private org.hibernate.SessionFactory rs.co.master.dao.UserRulesDaoImpl.sessionFactory;
>   nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()
>   [Ljavax/persistence/Index;

Here are my conf files
pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <org.springframework.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>

    <apache.tiles>3.0.3</apache.tiles>
    <!-- mz -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.hibernate-version>4.3.6.Final</org.hibernate-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.8.2</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.springdatajpa-version>1.7.0.RELEASE</org.springdatajpa-version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.35</mysql.connector.version>
    <com.fasterxml.jackson.core>2.5.0</com.fasterxml.jackson.core>
    <org.codehaus.jackson>1.9.13</org.codehaus.jackson>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <servlet-api-version>3.1.0</servlet-api-version>
    <jsp-version>2.1</jsp-version>
    <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib-ext-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-remoting</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.core}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.core}</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.core}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0a</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jsoup za preuzimanje html stranice -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
       <version>2.4</version>
   </dependency>


   <dependency>
     <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
     <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
     <version>2.7</version>
   </dependency>    
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
</dependencies>
      <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



<repositories>
    <!-- For Hibernate Validator -->

    <repository>
        <id>org.jboss.repository.release</id>
        <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>

        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>repo.springsource.org</id>
        <name>repo.springsource.org-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <name>SpringSource Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <name>Misko</name>
        <organization>JA</organization>
    </developer>
</developers>
```

Here are servlet-context.xml

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="rs.co" />

 <!-- Getting Database properties -->
   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>

   <mvc:annotation-driven />
   <!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:mymessages" />
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</beans:bean>

   <!-- View Resolver -->
   <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
   </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</beans:bean>


   <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="rs.co"></beans:property>

   </beans:bean>

   <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
   </beans:bean>

   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

HomeController.java

```
    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    UserRulesService userRulesService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    List<UserRulesBean> rules = userRulesService.listUserRules(1);
    model.addAttribute("rules", rules );
    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    return "home";
}
```

UserRulesService.java

```
    @Service
    public interface UserRulesService {

public void addUser(UserRulesBean User) throws Exception ;
public void deleteUser(Integer iduser, Integer role_id);
public boolean hasUser(Integer iduser);

public List<UserRulesBean> listUserRules(Integer iduser);

public UserRulesBean getRuleForUser(Integer iduser, Integer role_id);
public UserRulesBean findUser(String username);

public String getJsonByPage(Integer iduser, HttpServletRequest upit);

public UserRulesBean findUserRole(Integer iduser, Integer role_id);  

public Role getRole(int id);  

public List<Role>listRole();
    }
```

UserRulesDao.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserRulesDao {

public void addUser(UserRulesBean utenti) throws Exception ;
public void deleteUser(Integer iduser, Integer role_id);
public boolean hasUser(Integer iduser);

public List<UserRulesBean> listUserRules(Integer iduser);

public UserRulesBean getRuleForUser(Integer iduser, Integer role_id);
public UserRulesBean findUserRole(Integer iduser, Integer role_id);
public UserRulesBean findUser(String username);

public String getJsonByPage(Integer iduser, HttpServletRequest upit);

public Role getRole(int id); 
public  List<Role>listRole();
}
```

UserRolesDao.java

```
    @Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<UserRolesModel> listUserRolesModel() {

    List<UserRolesModel> csModel;

    String hql = "from UserRolesModel ";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);

    csModel = (List<UserRolesModel>) query.list();

    return csModel;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<UserRulesBean> listUserRules(Integer user_id){

    List<UserRulesBean> csBean;

    String hql = "select iduser as iduser, role_id as Role_id from UserRolesModel "
            + " where user_id = :user_id" ;
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql)
            .setInteger("user_id", user_id)
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers
            .aliasToBean(UserRulesBean.class));;

    csBean = (List<UserRulesBean>) query.list();

    return csBean;
}
```

Comment: How do you package your project?

Comment: I use Spring File Export to War

Comment: Here are a link for project [link](http://www.mfp.co.rs/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/testHibernate.zip)<br> I was installed Tomcat7 on Centos and tested project, and everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled tomcat on linux and it work now!